# Tab Order between Custom TextBox and Custom Button Controls

Tags: c#, tabs, tabindex, tab-ordering

I am developing a desktop application using C# using VS 2010.
I have created a custom text box control and a custom button control.
I have placed 5 custom text boxes and 2 custom buttons on a windows form.
the problem is :
I cannot tab through all the controls. when tabbing through the controls the focus only rotates between the text boxes.I cannot tab through the custom buttons.
Let me know if I am missing anything regarding tab order when creating custom buttons.

P.S.I have removed the focus queues for the button control.enabled the focus queues but it didn't help.

Regards
John

Answer (score 0):

You could try to focus it when the page loads

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    //Focus 001: Set the Default focus to the Name text Box    
    txtName.Focus();    
}

protected void txtFocustoLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{    
    //Focus 002: Set the focus to required control    
    txtOrderNo.Focus();    
}
```

But no guarantee in this example, you could provide us some of your buttons settings so we could look further into it.

Comment: I am adding the code for the custom button I created.I have placed a button inside a user control and set its properties by code.

Comment: also you are missing the point.I want to tab through the text boxes and buttons.for the time being I can only tab through text boxes.the buttons are not focused when tabbing through controls